# How to get 3D point coordinates given UV coordinates on a 3d plane object - Threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to build some simple data visualisation and my weapon of choice is Three.js.
I'have a series of PlaneGeometry meshes on which I apply a transparent texture dynamically created with a series of red square on it drawn at different opacity values.
My plan is to use those points to create other meshes ( eg. CylinderGeometry ) and place them on top of the red square with an height value based on the red square opacity value.
So far I could manage to find the UV values for each square and store it to an array, but I'm getting blocked at converting such red square UV coordinates to the 3D world coordinates system.
I've found several resource describing the same concept applied to a sphere, and surprisingly it is pretty straight forward, but no other resources about applying the same concept to other mesh.
[image: My current plane setup]

**How can I get the 3D coordinates of those red square inside the texture?**

Comment: I need to do this on sphere. Could you supply resources you said you found to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think this is it:

```
function texturePosToPlaneWorld(planeOb, texcoord)
{    
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    pos.x = (texcoord.x - 0.5) * PLANESIZE;
    pos.y = (texcoord.y - 0.5) * PLANESIZE;

    pos.applyMatrix4(planeOb.matrix);
    return pos;
}
```

Is used like this in the jsfiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/2/

```
var texcoord = new THREE.Vector2(0.8, 0.65);
var newpos = texturePosToPlaneWorld(planeOb, texcoord);
cubeOb.position.copy(newpos);
```

Planes are simple. The edge between vertices A, B -- vector A->B defines the direction for 'x' in your texture, and A->C similarily for the other direction in which the plane goes in the 3d space .. where you have texture's 'y' mapped on the plane.

Let's assume your pivot point is in the middle. So that's known in world space. Then as UV go from 0 to 1, e.g. UV coord (1.0, 0.5) would be in half way of the full width of the plane in the direction of the vector from of your Plane object pivot .. going from middle all the way to the edge. And then in the middle otherwise, where you have 0.5 in V (as in normalized texture y pixelcoord).

To know the coordinates of the vertices of the plane in world space, you just multiple them with the orientation of the object..

Given you know the size of your plane, you actually don't need to look at the vertices as the orientation of the plane is already in the object matrix. So you just need to adapt your UV coord to the pivot in middle (-0.5) and multiply with the plane size to get the point in plane space. Then the matrix multiplication converts that to world space.

Comment: How would you do this with a sphere?